# find the next pattern

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

What will be the next pattern? Why...
thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The second option from the top.

> Let's label the dot positions in the $3\times 3$ grid as $1$ in the top-left corner, $2$ in the middle of the top row, $3$ in the top-right corner, all the way up to $9$ in the bottom-right corner.

> In the first picture, the blue dots are at $4, 5, 7, 8$;
>  In the second picture, the blue dots are at $5, 6, 8, 9$;
>  In the third picture, the blue dots are at $6, 7, 9, 1$,
>  and so we can see that the blue dots shift up by one every time, until when it has reached No $9$, in which case in the picture after it will go back to No $1$.

> This means that you should choose the second option from the top, with the blue dots at $7, 8, 1, 2$.